# Combine columns and sort the values before creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

I am making a python script that I want to combine several columns of string data and sort them alphabetically before creating the new column. To simplify my example here is a really simple example of the format of the data I am dealing with:

```
Ingredient 1, Ingredient 2, Ingredient 3
pickles, beef, mayo
sugar, flour, eggs
```

the final product I am trying to achieve is a new column where the 3 ingredients are combined and alphabetized:

```
Ingredient 1, Ingredient 2, Ingredient 3, Ingredient Summary
pickles, beef, mayo, beef; mayo; pickles 
sugar, flour, eggs, eggs; flour; sugar
```

I just started learning python about two weeks ago with the goal of scraping some data from websites and organizing it into a csv to manipulate in excel. I have been successful at scraping data from websites, but I really struggle with modifying the CSV data. Here is the code that I have so far, and as you can see the code currently doesn't sort I could only figure out how to combine the data into a new column.

```
import pandas

CSV_file = pandas.read_csv('ingredients.csv')
df = pandas.DataFram(CSV_file)

df['Ingredient Summary'] = df['Ingredient 1'] + '; ' + df['Ingredient 2']
print(df['Ingredient Summary'])
```

I am hoping that someone can point me to an easy solution to accomplish this. I have looked a lot of posts in this forum, but can just not figure out how to do this.

I was trying to turn the rows into a lists and then sort the lists, and then finally print the list as a new row. I wasn't successful in that approach, and was starting to think I was doing this the hard way which is why I am now asking for someone else help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your dataframe -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',\s*', engine='python')
df

  Ingredient 1 Ingredient 2 Ingredient 3
0      pickles         beef         mayo
1        sugar        flour         eggs
```

Call `np.sort`, load the result into a `Series`, and call `.str.join` -

```
df['Summary'] = pd.Series(np.sort(df.values, axis=1).tolist()).str.join('; ')
df

0    beef; mayo; pickles
1     eggs; flour; sugar
dtype: object
```

Save to CSV again using `to_csv` -

```
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: I wasn't able to try out your solution until now. It worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond you have saved me a lot of additional frustration. I voted for your answer but it won't let me count it yet because my reputation is too low.

Comment: @Marcel Thanks for accepting. You can also upvote answers if you liked them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_ingredients(row):
    return ';'.join(row.sort_values().tolist())

df['Ingredient Summary'] = df.apply(sort_ingredients, axis=1)
```

Comment: Assuming you meant `sort_values` instead of sorted values, this is still going to be slower than calling `np.sort`. Always avoid using `apply` if you can.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I ended up using the other answer with `np.sort` because of the comment about `sort_values` being slower.